# Minecraft pe does not work SEVER DISCONECTED

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just downloaded the new Minecraft PE 12.1 alpha buid 8 version and every server I press it says server disconnected. Why does this do this and what should I do?

Comment: Is the server online? Are you online? Are you using the same version as the server?

Comment: As with all [tag:minecraft] questions, we need a lot more information. What mobile OS version are you using? What game versions are you using? We don't magically know your problem, you need to tell us!

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can cause a server to disconnect you. When you become disconnected from a server, the majority of the time, it will provide an error message.

Some other notable mentions as to why this is an issue could be:

- Your client is newer than the server
- The server is newer than your client
- Your game might have some bugs, try reinstalling it
- Try another server, that server may have some compatibility issues
- Last, but certainly not least, the server may be full